# A very basic doubt about who should start an action in DDD (domain-driven design)

Tags: domain-driven-design

When I read about DDD, it is always said that it is about behaviors, said in another way, actions than can be performed.

My doubt is that who should start the actions.

Suppose I have a bounded context (BC) about orders. For the example I will tell just a very few rules.

- An employee receives an order.
- The employee creates the order.
- The employee will add lines to the order.

Normally, in the examples that I see, is in the application layer where the order is created and then persisted in the database, something like that:

```
public class CreateOrderApplicationService
{
    public Order CreateOrder(long paramIdEmployee)
    {
        Order myOrder = Order.Create(paramIdEmployee);
        _repository.Add(myOrder);
        _repository.Commit();
    }
}
```

However, I think that an order can't be created by itself, in fact, in the rules and ubiquitous language it is said an employee receives an order, the employee creates an order... and so on, or at least it is implicit that it is always a person, a user, an employee or another kind of person who do something. Or another process of the system, that could be considered as another kind of user.

So from this point of view, I think that perhaps another solution could be this:

```
public class CreateOrderApplicationService
{
    public Order CreateOrder(long paramIdEmployee)
    {
        Employee myEmpolyee = _repository.GetEmployee(paramIdEmployee);
        Order myOrder = myEmpolyee.CreateOrder();
        _repository.Commit();
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    long Id;
    List<Order> Orders;

    public Order CreateOrder()
    {
        Order myOrder = Order.Create(Id);
        Orders.Add(myOrder);
        return Order;
    }
}
```

NOTE: here, I get the employee from the order repository, because if I am not wrong, the common practice is to have one repository for each bounded context, so in my bounded context a need an employee. Anyway, the example tries to show that I get the employee from a repository (no matter from which) to get the employee to perform the action of creation of the order.

In this case, the employee just delegate the create of the order to the order entity, but it is the start point of the action.

But thinking in this solution, it is true that then, all actions and all bounded contexts will need a person entity and all actions will be done through the entity person, and it seems an odd solution. But from another point of view, it seems intuitive that any action is performed by a person and in ubiquitous language it is said that an employee creates the order, it is not said an order is created (in a general way).

So perhaps for people that is starting with DDD, can be a bit confuse, because depending on the way to use the ubiquitous language, the solution can be different, or lead to think in an incorrect way, or lead to use a technical solution, in this case, who starts the action, from the way the experts, that are not technicians, just experts about the problem to solve.

In summary, I would like to know if the solution to start every action through the user is a bad idea or not.

Thanks.

Comment: In the line `Order myOrder = newOrder.Create(paramIdEmployee);`, what is `newOrder`? Another, former existing order object? I don't see any declaration for it. Or did you mix this up with something like `Order myOrder = new Order(paramIdEmployee)`?

Comment: I wanted to tell new Order.Create(paramIdEmployee), like you tell at last. I didn't write an space between new and Order.Create(oaranIdEmployee). So newOrder is not another class or entity.

Comment: `new Order.Create(paramIdEmployee)` or `new Order(paramIdEmployee)`? You should really care for those details. Please take the time, use the edit button and fix your typos. Your question is hard to understand when those details are wrong.

Comment: Well, I leave Order.Create() as way to create an order, as factory, instead to use the constrcutor, it is true it could be a bit confuse. Anyway what i was trying to expose  was where to create the order more than the way to create, if to create it through an instance of the employee that is used in the application layer or create the order directly in the application layer.

Comment: Research [UML sequence diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram), also known as the "swim lane" diagram. This will help you think about overall flow, object interaction, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDD does not dictate such details, and even if it would, it is not a "law" you blindly have to follow. I recommend to stop thinking about what some dogma might say, and start thinking more about what makes most sense. A code line

```
    Order myOrder = Order.Create(paramIdEmployee);
```

is fine when all an `Order` constructor requires is the employee ID, and

```
    Employee myEmployee = _repository.GetEmployee(paramIdEmployee);
    Order myOrder = myEmployee.CreateOrder();
```

is fine when order creation requires more than just the employees' id, but more data of an Employee object which has to be retrieved first. It is also ok when your whole use case requires an object `myEmployee` with an newly added order object afterwards.

But when you just discard myEmployee after the order creation, this becomes unnecessarily overcomplicated. It is also not very efficient to query an employee object first from the repo (which might cause a database or network query) just for passing an ID around you already have at hand.

Coming back to your question about "who starts an action" - I think for this you have to take a step back look at a whole use case. For example, lets assume this is some GUI application and its starts with a *real person* (lets say an employee in an company) sitting in front of a computer and trying to "create a real order". Then when that person presses some button in the UI, this will initiate a message from a presentation layer which might be passed through some other layers and finally call the `CreateOrderApplicationService`. Since the user is somehow connected to the system, at the time when `CreateOrderApplicationService` get called, chances are not bad there exists already an employee object for the person which can be passed into the service call, which would then look like this:

```
public class CreateOrderApplicationService
{
    public Order CreateOrder(Employee employee)
    {
        Order myOrder = employee.CreateOrder();
        _repository.AddOrder(myOrder);
        _repository.Commit();
    }
}
```

But in detail, the whole use case might work differently and an employee object may not always be at hand when the orders are created, in which case the simple `Order.Create` approach is probably the most simple (and hence fine) solution.

Comment: Thanks for clearing some questions. If I understand correctly, in you code is the client who create the instance of the employee and the application layer use it diretly. Wouldn't it better the application layer get the information from the database to be sure is correct and not trust in what the client send to the service?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía: I did not specificially mention in which layer the passed employee instance is created (but it is surely some layer at the server when this is a web application, which I also did not state).  Such question can only be answered within the context of a real system.

Answer (score 2):

In DDD we’re not modeling the real world. The model should be able to solve the business problem at hand. And while it’s true that this should be done using a language that’s created in collaboration with domain experts, this does not mean the relations between the domain concepts should exactly match reality!

In a model (BC) that’s focused on order processing, do we really need an Employee aggregate? Or is it perhaps enough to know which employee created the order? In that case a simple employeeId would suffice.

So while you’re right that *in the real world* an order does not create itself, in a model that is created to solve a specific business problem, a factory method called `Order.Create(employeeId)` is totally acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I know, there isn't a good authoritative answer here....

> i can be thought that an order can't be created by itself, in fact, in the rules and ubiquitous language it is said an employee receives an order, the employee create an order...

One interesting perspective on this was written by [Udi Dahan](https://udidahan.com/2009/06/29/dont-create-aggregate-roots/):

> Customers don’t just appear out of thin air.

His position at the time was that you would use a thing you already know about to create the new thing.

Following the pattern he describes, you would get an in memory representation of an employee, and then delegate to that code the problem of creating an order and adding it to the appropriate collection.

That said, I haven't found anything like other DDD authors/influencers/practitioners expressing similar ideas.  Udi seems to have been on his own island.